# Cufon text disappears when using Yahoo Babelfish

Tags: translation, yahoo-api, cufon

Has anyone experienced this?  Cufon text disappears when using Yahoo Babelfish.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It's because the babelfished page is located on Yahoo's server, which 
means that the domain-protected font doesn't work. Doh!